# Problem in getting the image from web in android studio

Tags: android

I want to get the image from the internet. I write the code like this many time but now it didn't work it hasn't any error but didn't work

Hi there. I want to get the image from the internet . I write the code like this many time but now it didn't work it hasn't any error but didn't work 
(I write it twice for StackOverflow error: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

ImageView imgValue ;
Button btnDownload ;
EditText edtUrl ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imgValue = findViewById(R.id.imgValue);
    btnDownload = findViewById(R.id.btnDownload);
    edtUrl = findViewById(R.id.edtUrl);

    btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            GetImage imageDownloader = new GetImage();
            imageDownloader.execute("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg");
        }
    });


}
private class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... strings) {

        Bitmap downloadedImage = null ;
        String theUrl = strings[0];
        try {
            URL url = new URL(theUrl);
            InputStream stream = url.openStream() ;
            downloadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }

        return downloadedImage ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        super.onPostExecute(bitmap);

        imgValue.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ddd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What result(s) did you expect?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad onPostExecute did't work imgValue is a ImageView and i expect to downloaded image show in that . also Toast message didn't work

Comment: Can you log your code?

Comment: Checkout this article: https://android.jlelse.eu/fresco-android-image-library-c680b17b4a2a

Answer (score 1):

use **[Facebook Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco)** library for this. It's easy to implement.

I also wrote an article for it: [Fresco — Android Image Library](https://android.jlelse.eu/fresco-android-image-library-c680b17b4a2a)

Sample code is here:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
        android:id="@+id/coverImage"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_150sdp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:transitionName="movie_image_transition"
        app:placeholderImage="@color/colorPrimary"
        fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
        fresco:fadeDuration="300"
        fresco:placeholderImage="@color/colorPrimary"
        fresco:viewAspectRatio="0.66" />
```

And java code is:

```
coverImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(
  "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d7/Android_robot.svg"
));
```

Answer (score 0):

whe don't you just workd with **[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)** , simple and efficient!

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUri, imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the simplest way by Picasso library 
https://square.github.io/picasso/
and code is

```
Picasso.get().load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```